# Remove element from heapq

Tags: python, heap

I am trying to implement the AStar search algorithm and I'm having trouble removing elements from the fringe (open list). I push my `Cells` in like this:

```
heapq.heappush(myHeap, (priority, cell)
```

My cell class looks like this:

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.X = int(x)
        self.Y = int(y)
        self.G = float("inf")
        self.parent = None

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.X, self.Y) < (other.X, other.Y)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return int(self.X) == int(other.X) and int(self.Y) == int(other.Y)
```

Is there a way I can just do `heapq.remove(cell)` or `heapq.heappop(cell)` to remove the entry from the heap and then reheapify it?

Currently, I'm doing it like this but I don't think it's working correctly as I get an infinite loop sometimes:

```
def remove(self, item):
    index = 0

    for i in range(len(myHeap)):
        if(myHeap[i][1] == item):
            index = i

    # Move slot to be removed to top of heap
    while index > 0:
        up = int((index + 1) / 2 - 1)
        self.heap[index] = self.heap[up]
        index = up

    # Remove top of heap and restore heap property
    heapq.heappop(myHeap)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the regular list methods also on your list `myHeap`. So first remove some particular element from the list, then heapify and push an element with new priority:

```
myHeap.remove((priority, cell))
heapq.heapify(myHeap)
heapq.heappush(myHeap, (new_priority, cell))
```

Comment: I can't keep track of the priority so using remove in that way won't work for me.